# Is there an effective algorithm for finding "minimal discovery times" for large graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, markov-chains, random-walks

Consider a large, probably sparse graph with Markovian random walkers on it. 
Define the *discovery time* as the expected time to first reach a vertex by 
random walk from a uniform start. Are there effective ways to find the 
discovery times for all or almost all vertices?

Comment: So you're asking about the cover time (or a variant).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas somehow. I want use some random-walker derived score for the vertices of my graph instead of page rank.